# Swap values in an array recursively

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

The following method has to recursively swap all the values in an array of integers. I must use the helper method `reverse()`. How can I accomplish this? What would the base case be in this problem? I tried making it `start <= count`, `start == count/2`, and `start >= count` but none of them have worked.
Start is the index of the value to be swapped, and count is the amount of elements in the array

```
    public void reverse()
    {     
       reverseRecurse(list, 0, count);
    }

    private void reverseRecurse(int[] list, int start, int count)
    {         
         if (start >= count/2) 
         {
           int temp = list[start];
           list[start] = list[count];
           list[count] = temp;     
         }

         else
         {   
           reverseRecurse(list, ++start, --count);
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void reverse()
{     
   reverseRecurse(list, 0, count-1); // count - 1 is index of last element
}

private void reverseRecurse(int[] list, int start, int end)
{         
     if (start < end) 
     {
       int temp = list[start];
       list[start] = list[end];
       list[end] = temp;
       reverseRecurse(list, start + 1, end - 1);
     }
}
```

It's easier to go by indexes so I use `start` and `end`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! So I did not need an else at all.